# yii filter in two cgrdiview with same model

Tags: php, yii

I have two cgridview that using same model.
When I use filters, the textfield names are the same (model class).

It's possible modify this name?

example:

```
$model1 = new ClassName;
$model2 = new ClassName;
if(isset($_GET['cgrdiview_1'])) {
    $model1->attributes = $_GET['cgrdiview_1'];
}
if(isset($_GET['cgrdiview_2'])) {
    $model2->attributes = $_GET['cgrdiview_2'];
}
```

Instead I have:

```
$_GET['model_class']
```

for both cgridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with custom filter in each column:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'cgridview_2',
    'dataProvider' => $data,
    'filter' => $filter,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'column1',
            'filter' => CHtml::textField("cgridview2[column1]", $filter->column1),
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'column2',
            'filter' => CHtml::textField("cgridview2[column2]", $object->column2),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible by adding an id field.

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id.

If you check the [Yii API Documentation for CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) You can see that you can set an [id field](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#id-detail) for the CGridview.

In your view, change the CGridview code to contain the following:

```
'id' => 'cgridview_1'
```

This code needs to be added at the top of your gridview. For example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'cgridview_1',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'title',          // display the 'title' attribute
        'category.name',  // display the 'name' attribute of the 'category' relation
        'content:html',   // display the 'content' attribute as purified HTML
        array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
            'name'=>'create_time',
            'value'=>'date("M j, Y", $data->create_time)',
        ),
        array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
            'name'=>'authorName',
            'value'=>'$data->author->username',
        ),
        array(            // display a column with "view", "update" and "delete" buttons
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Ok but is there a way to send the cgridview id though the request? As I need to make separate queries according to the requesting cgridview and its filters.

Comment: an ID field is always send in a POST/GET request if it is in your form. I would suggest to test it by doing a var_dump in your controller

Comment: The problem is those two cgridview are not inside a form.

Comment: Then how are you using the filter? the filter normally submits everything via POST if I am not mistaken

Comment: I use the filter via GET

Comment: Then you can also add the id field to the filter. Maybe also add your view code to your question. It will help solving your problem